# Automatic dropdown with a parent button that takes you to another page in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a dropdown menu with bootstrap that when hovering over the button in the navbar menu the sub menu appears automatically and when pressing it it takes you to another different page: I tried the following code but the sub menu collapses only by clicking on the parent button:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="services.htm">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="tourism/tourism.htm">Tourism</a></li>
                        <li><a href="trade/trade.htm">International Trade</a></li>
                        <li><a href="heath/health.htm">Health Care</a></li>
                        <li><a href="real_/real-esate.htm">Real Estate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Invesment</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Legal Process</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="read.htm">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
```

And When Adding the following css code:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
display: block;    
   }
```

The the sub menu collapsed just by hovering over the services button, but when pressing the services button the browser is still unable to take me to the page services.htm as shown in the case upstairs. How can this case be solved ?

Comment: "... with a mother mutton ..." ??? ?? ? ???

Comment: For the record, I liked mother mutton better.

Comment: I didn't have enough coffee in me to get past the idea of a doting sheep mom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
display: block;   
position: absolute;
top: 23px; 
}

ul.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu {
display:none;
position: absolute;
top: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Is your sub menu appearing over top of your parent link? If so, you may want to add positioning to the second ul class.

Comment: such as:

position: absolute;
  top: 23px;

something like that

Comment: I edited my answer, hope this helps what you're trying to fix.